# Conta SQL como fazer soma e subtração

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Estou começando a aprender *SQL* preciso fazer uma conta,  tenho um *select* para um relatório onde preciso fazer uma conta para mostrar um outro valor nos campos desse relatório e a fórmula não pode aparecer no mesmo.

**Query:**

````
SELECT  
    application_name, 
    sum(cancellation_total) as cancellation,
    sum(active_base_total) as active_base, 
    sum(new_subscriber_total)as new_subscriber,
    inserted_date
from report.dashboard_daily_igpm 
where carrier_id IN (122)
   and inserted_date >= DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm,0,GetDate()-1) - 0, 0)
  ```
````

A conta deve ser essa:

```
 Base (Dia 1) = Base (Dia -1) + Altas (Dia 1) - Bajas (Dia 1)

sum(active_base_total)=sum(active_base_total)+sum(new_subscriber_total)- sum(cancellation_total)
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz assim

```
SELECT  
    application_name, 
    sum(cancellation_total) as cancellation,
    sum(active_base_total) as active_base, 
    sum(new_subscriber_total)as new_subscriber,
    sum(active_base_total)+sum(new_subscriber_total)- sum(cancellation_total) as nome_da_formula
    inserted_date
from report.dashboard_daily_igpm 
where carrier_id IN (122)
   and inserted_date >= DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm,0,GetDate()-1) - 0, 0)
```